# can't find published React component module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I published a React component to NPM and when trying to use it in another project I am not able to find the module!

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-subreddit-posts' in '/Users/kyle.calica/Code/exmaple/app/src'
```

I was having trouble with creating a Webpack bundle which I could import from when developing. I believe it is because I am making ES6 class notations but trying to compile so that I can import? I was able to "fix" it. But now I'm having trouble using it.

Here is my React component's `webpack.prod.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["react"],
              plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  }
};
```

Here is my entry JS file for the component, `index.js` a good example of how I'm making the classes in my React component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListContainer from './ListContainer';
import ListItemComponent from './ListItemComponent';

const redditAPI = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/';

export default class SubredditPosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redditPosts: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const uri = `${redditAPI}${this.props.subreddit}.json`;
    fetch(uri)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(this.handlePosts)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  handlePosts = (posts) => {
    const apiPosts = posts.data.children.map((post, index) => {
      return {
        key: index,
        title: post.data.title,
        media: this.getMediaFromPost(post),
        link: post.data.url
      };
    });

    this.setState({
      redditPosts: apiPosts,
      isLoading: false
     });
  }

  getMediaFromPost = (post) => {
    const extension = post.data.url.split('.').pop();

    if (post.data.hasOwnProperty('preview') &&  !extension.includes('gif')) {
      return post.data.preview.images[0].source.url;
    }

    //do not use includes! because of Imgur's gifv links are not embeddable
    if (extension === 'gif' || extension.includes('jpg') ||  extension.includes('jpeg')) {
      return post.data.url;
    }

    //if can't load media then place placeholder
    return this.props.placeholder;
  }

    render() {
      return(
        <ListContainer display={this.props.display}>
        { !this.state.isLoading && this.state.redditPosts.map(post => (
          <ListItemComponent
            display={this.props.display}
            key={post.key}
            link={post.link}
            media={post.media}
            title={post.title}
            height={this.props.height}
            width={this.props.width}
          />
        ))}
        </ListContainer>
      );
    }
}
```

And here is the `App.js` in my project trying to consume the published React component that I pulled from NPM:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SubredditPosts  from 'react-subreddit-posts';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
        <SubredditPosts
          subreddit="aww"
          display="tile"
          placeholder="some_link_image_url_OR_image_path"
          width="250px"
          height="250px"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong with my bundling and exporting of the React component? 
Or am I just importing it wrong?

Comment: Is it present inside your node_modules folder?

Comment: @Volodymyr yes it is. I have physically seen it. I tried to use a absolute path but got a warning that you cannot do so outside of my source folder -- my example app uses `create-react-app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installed your package and it turns out to be a bad publish.

When you import a package from node_modules, node/webpack finds the directory, reads a package.json file in it, then imports the file indicated by the `main` field in package.json. If any of those steps fail your import will fail to resolve.

Your package.json says `"main": "dist/index.js"` but there's no dist directory in the release, only a lib directory.

Changing the field to `"main": "lib/index.js"` would probably work, but there's other issues as well. Your dependencies are all over the place. `devDependencies` are packages need only by developers working on the package. It's used for build tools, testing tools, linters, etc. `dependencies` are need for the package to work correctly. The difference is that `dependnecies` of a dependency will be installed when you install a package, but `devDependencies` of a dependency won't be installed.

In your case, you need react and react-dom in `dependencies` and everything else in `devDependnecies`. Also npm is always installed globally and you don't need it in your package.json at all.

I'd recommend you look up a guide for maintaining an open source package and/or check how an existing one is set up. It's not too hard to understand but there's a lot of things you should know that you just don't care about when developing an app.

Comment: btw also look up how you can use `npm link` (although I really recommend yarn for this) to test changes to your npm package locally without having to publish every time you make a change

Comment: Awesome thank you! I thought I was still messing up the ES6 classes with `import/export` . So my aim was to have a project with no dependencies on anything else. I don't know how my `dependencies` got mixed up with my `devDependencies` I fix that for sure. Yeah I'll try and find a good guide. I'll see if making those changes fix anything and I'll report here and mark yours as the answer

Comment: awesome! thank you! ever since my refactor, I broke a lot with webpack and my build. Now I see I have other things I broke but at least this puts me back on the path! Thank you so much! I might comment here with any resources I find to document everything with this issue. Sorry for any future spam.

Comment: also i think you mean `build` dir not `lib`, I don't have a `lib` directory.